# how to have one big column and three rows where one of the rows is 3 columns in a grid in css

Tags: css, grid, row

I am new to grid layouts in CSS and I want to have a simple layout with one column
and three rows but one of the rows has to be again divided into three columns

so it will be something like below where 2, 3, 4 have to be in the same row equally spaced
or controllable.

[image]

Here is my grid structure:

```
<div class="grid_container">

    <div class="card" id="about_me">
      <p>
        1
      </p>
    </div>

    <div class="card card-small" id="">
      <p>
        2
      </p>
    </div>

    <div class="card card-small" id="">
      <p>
        3
      </p>
    </div>

    <div class="card card-small" id="">
      <p>
        4
      </p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="card" id="">
      <p>
        5
      </p>
    </div>

    </div>
```

I feel like using flex-box for the three rows, but thats not probably what I should do
as grid probably has its own logic and control to generate such a layout.

Comment: Why not use CSS Grid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this would work for you if you want to use css grid:

```css
    .grid-container {
       display: grid;
       grid-template-columns: repeat(3, minmax(0, 1fr));
       row-gap: 10px;
       text-align: center;
    }
    .full-row {
      grid-column: span 3 / span 3;
      border: dashed red;
    }
    .one-third-row {
      grid-column: span 1 / span 1;
      border: dashed red;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="grid-container">

    <div class="full-row" id="about_me">
      <p>
        1
      </p>
    </div>

    <div class="one-third-row" id="">
      <p>
        2
      </p>
    </div>

    <div class="one-third-row" id="">
      <p>
        3
      </p>
    </div>

    <div class="one-third-row" id="">
      <p>
        4
      </p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="full-row" id="">
      <p>
        5
      </p>
    </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: yea this was what i was looking for, but i decided use the grid-area

Comment: Ok, great! I've updated the answer with borders and text alignment

Answer (score 1):

1. **using `grid-column` css**

> - work fine also with `gap`s
> - only one div that contain all the cards

```css
.grid_container {
  display: grid;
  gap: 0.5rem;
}

.card {
  border: 1px dashed red;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid_container">
  <div style="grid-column: 1/4" class="card" id="about_me">
    <p>1</p>
  </div>

  <div style="grid-column: 1/2" class="card card-small" id="">
    <p>2</p>
  </div>

  <div style="grid-column: 2/3" class="card card-small" id="">
    <p>3</p>
  </div>

  <div style="grid-column: 3/4" class="card card-small" id="">
    <p>4</p>
  </div>

  <div style="grid-column: 1/4" class="card" id="">
    <p>5</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

---

---

---

---

---

2. **using flexbox**

Another easier solution can be using `grid` when is necessary, or `flexbox` when is necessary.

so the 3, 4, 5 cards can be wrapped inside a `<div>` and make that div with `flexbox`

and the parent element `grid`

[image]

```css
.grid_container {
  display: grid;
}

.flex_container {
  display: flex;
}

.flex_container>* {
  flex: 1;
}

.card {
  border: 1px dashed red;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid_container">
  <div class="card" id="about_me">
    <p>1</p>
  </div>

  <div class="flex_container">
    <div class="card card-small" id="">
      <p>2</p>
    </div>

    <div class="card card-small" id="">
      <p>3</p>
    </div>

    <div class="card card-small" id="">
      <p>4</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card" id="">
    <p>5</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: that doesnt answer the question but yes, also i want to know how i can bring two gaps to be equal because i have a gap of 1.0 rem and when the 2, 3 and 4 are put together there is now a margin on 2rem side by side...

Comment: solved now, edited the answer